# Codeigniter not taking arguments from URL

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-url

I have a function that needs to pull arguments from the URL like CI is supposed to do.  But it's not doing it.  My URL is domain.com/lasers/en/acme.

My class Lasers is:

```
class Lasers extends CI_Controller {

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->load->model('products_model');
        $this->load->model('common_model');
        $this->load->model('select_country_model'); 
        $this->load->model('markets_materials_model');  
    }


function index($lang = NULL, $laser = NULL) 
{   
    $query = $this->products_model->get_product_content($laser, $lang);
}
```

The model is loaded in the constructor.  The $lang I need is "en" and the $laser I need is "acme".  So why isn't this working?  The arguments in the function are in the correct order, so I can't see what's wrong.

Comment: How are you accessing this? What's your url?

Comment: Also, have you made changes to your routes file in `config/routes.php`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default you cant pass arguments to the `index` method of a controller

if you go to `domain.com/lasers/en/acme` it is looking in the `lasers` controller for a method called `en`.. (which doesn't exist) and trying to pass a single parameter of `acme` to it

Theres a few solutions, probly the easiest is to use a different method (not index) then use routes to make the URLs work.

add something like this to your `config/routes.php`

```
$route['^lasers/(:any)/(:any)'] = "lasers/get_products/$1/$2";
```

Then use a method like this instead of `index`:

```
function get_products($lang = NULL, $laser = NULL) {   
    $query = $this->products_model->get_product_content($laser, $lang);
}
```

.. OR you could use [_remap](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/controllers.html#remapping) to override the default behaviour

Comment: hi, that's the regex for "starts with", just in case for some reason u have a controller called 'biglasers' or 'my_lasers' or something, to make it not match those controllers

Answer (score 0):

Does it work if you write "domain.com/lasers/index/en/acme"?

If you write domain.com/lasers/en/acme, it will look for the "En" function, $lang being "acme", and $laser remaining NULL.

Comment: Which error does it give then when you access via "domain.com/lasers/en/acme"? Does it enter the index function? Are you using any CI routing?